# Uncertain how to proceed with combinatorics proof

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

The problem is as follows: let $n_1, n_2,..., n_t$ be positive integers.  Prove that if $n_1+n_2+...+n_t-t+1$ objects are placed into $t$ boxes, then for some $i, i=1, 2, ..., t$, the $i$th box contains at least $n_i$ objects.

I'm having difficulty getting started in developing a proof because I have no intuition as to why this should be true or whether or not it actually is.  Could someone help get me started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to think about it is to rewrite $n_1+n_2+\cdots n_t - t+1$ as

$$(n_1-1)+(n_2-1)+\cdots+(n_t-1)+1$$

and then think that if you want try to avoid putting $n_i$ balls into the $i$th box, you can put at most $n_1-1$ balls in the first box, $n_2-1$ in the second, etc., which will leave $1$ ball left, which will have to go somewhere.

Comment: For $i=1$ I see why this approach works.  But why is this true for $i>1$?  It seems that for $i>1$, the extra ball could simply be placed in the $i-1$th box.  Because there aren't $t$ extra objects, I'm not understanding why this works for some arbitrary $i$.

Comment: @user93189, try thinking through an explicit example with some small numbers, say $t=3$ and $n_1,n_2,n_3=3,4$ and $5$, so that $n_1+n_2+n_3-t+1=10$.  If you try to avoid putting $n_i$ balls in the $i$th box, you can only put $2$ balls in the first box, $3$ in the second, and $4$ in the third, so what can you do with the $10$th ball?

Answer (score 2):

A counterexample would consist of $t$ boxes with $b_i$ balls, $1 \leq i \leq t$, such that $$b_i \leq n_i-1$$ for all $1 \leq i \leq t$.  Now find a upper bound on $\sum_{i=1}^t b_i$ using the above inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that the $i$-th box always contains $< n_i$ objects.  Then what is the largest the total number of objects could be?  (This occurs when the $i$-th box has $n_i - 1$ objects.)  But how many objects are there in total?